# Comparing columns in Google sheets to find common values (number of) and unique values (number of)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a big dataset so made a smaller example to explain.

Basically I want to make the two tables on the right using the information in the table on the left.

The first table shows how many people have common values for color.
Eg. How many people are in Red and Blue.

The second table excludes the people who have the two colors in common and only looks at the unique ones.
Eg. How many people who are in Red but not in Blue (and vice versa).

I'm struggling to figure out the formulas to use...and whether I need an interim step or not.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed53e.png)

I've tried Vlookup but not sure it's what I need in this case. Am not familiar with all the google sheet formula options and couldn't find something that helped with this particular case from googling or searching youtube.

Link to sheet:
[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-lmlpOaWSLjEe8zMOu5krma5dpZXHITqXEmPsnppD8o/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Instead of an image; can you maybe provide the sample data set in a tabular form here OR a sheet would suffice too?!

Comment: Added link to Google sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

- `Green` has trailing space character in `column_B` which you may want to fix (highlighted in screenshot)
- Clear the ranges `F3:I6` & `F12:I15` prior to applying these formulas in Cells `F3` & `F12`
- couple of formula-derived output values are different from your manually entered expected output; which you may need to double check

***F3 formula***:

```
=makearray(counta(E3:E6),counta(F2:I2),lambda(r,c,if(index(E3:E6,r)=index(F2:I2,,c),,
          let(Σ,filter(A:A,B:B=index(E3:E6,r)),counta(ifna(filter(Σ,xmatch(Σ,filter(A:A,B:B=index(F2:I2,,c))))))))))
```

***F12 formula***:

```
=makearray(counta(E3:E6),counta(F2:I2),lambda(r,c,if(index(E3:E6,r)=index(F2:I2,,c),,
          let(Σ,filter(A:A,B:B=index(F2:I2,,c)),counta(filter(Σ,iserror(xmatch(Σ,filter(A:A,B:B=index(E3:E6,r))))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that was really amazing!

Yes I did a rough manual calculation as an example so most likely got some wrong.

Your answer was tremendously helpful. I don't think I would have come up with it on my own so I'm glad I asked here.

Could I possibly trouble you to come up with a formula that compares with all the colors. Eg. How many in Red that are not in Orange, Blue & Green combined?

Your formulas are pretty advanced to me and I'll be studying and trying to figure them out. Thank you very much for the help!